# Google App Engine: Should two tightly related entities be combined?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In an application I'm developing I have two entities that are tightly related (EntityA, EntityB). EntityB is never accessed without EntityA, but EntityA is often accessed without Entity B. Also, EntityB can be very large, while EntityA is moderately sized.

Is there any disadvantage to adding EntityB to EntityA (as a structured property/copying the field)? Thereby increasing the size of EntityA, and eliminating EntityB. Or should I just use a key property in EntityA to reference EntityB, and use an extra get whenever EntityB is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is at maximum only one Entity B for each entity A, you can make entity B a child of Entity A. This makes it easy to retrieve it - you don't even have to reference its key in the parent Entity.

There is no reason to combine two entities if you often need one without the other. There is a small performance penalty from loading more data than you need.

Comment: Yes, there is only one EntityB for every EntityA. So you're recommending using an ancestor query to get EntityB? Isn't that much slower than getting by key?

Comment: You don't need an ancestor query if you only have one entity B. When you create entity B, you can give it an id = 1. Now you can easily construct a key to retrieve it using id of its patent entity A.